# Making two Component same height when one is a array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, height

I am learning React and Redux and now I have this problem.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aspnetcorereactredux-bdhjf?file=/src/components/Logger.jsx)

I want this two `Component` to be side by side and always have the same height even if `Component2` grow larger since it's a `map`.

Try like this:

- Search for book title "dep"
- Watch the log grow pushing down the screen

Here's an image showing the `Component2` getting larger then `Component1` and I don't want that I have added `style={{overflowY:"scroll"}` to `Component2` but don't understand why it pushes down anyway.

[image]

I tried using `FlexBox` but it's not working:

```
.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
  
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
```

I don't want to set a fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to do more CSS here.

Try to add a `max-height: 300px` in that component that have the `overflow-y`.

Comment: yea it's works like that but is there a way without setting fixed height?

Comment: @Kid, In order to active the overflow, is mandatory to have a height or width with a maximum or static value. So on this case, yes we need it.

You can use this library [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window).

Comment: We can manage it without setting fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this without setting height manually.

So, I've added a ref for the form.

```
this.formRef = React.createRef();
```

Used ref into the `form` tag.

```
<form ref={this.formRef}
```

And added an extra property to the state:

```
formHeight: "200px"
```

At `componentDidMount` hook I've assigned the height of the form into the state.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        localBook: {
          ...prevState.localBook
        },
        formHeight:
          this.formRef.current.parentElement.clientHeight.toString() + "px"
      }),
      () => {}
    );
  }
```

At your `logger` component I've added another style from `props`.

```
<div style={{ overflowY: "scroll", maxHeight: props.maxHeight }}>
```

And passed the prop from the parent:

```
<EnhancedTable maxHeight={this.state.formHeight} />
```

Demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aspnetcorereactredux-forked-hjxjk).

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: If the answer works for you then mark it as accepted.